# New upload dialog shows no indication of an upload happening when one uses the copy functionality

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, user-experience

Currently, when using the "paste image here" functionality of the new image upload dialog, there is zero indication that something is going on. I click a button. The button doesn't respond, and no part of the page changes. I can't tell if I've screwed up, or if the page has hanged (this leads to me incessantly clicking the upload button). I just have to wait and see if an upload *does* happen. I've gotten used to it, but somehow this seems like bad UX to me ([I wonder what the experts think](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/37416/11396)). A user should get some sort of indication that the computer is listening.

Compare this with the indication given by the new upload dialog when you upload a link:

[image]

Even better, the old image upload dialog, where there's no doubt that the system *is* listening:

[image]

Could this be fixed so that there is some indication of an upload for the paste-to-upload? Preferably one of those spinning things or the standard StackExchange "dots" progress indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, an "Uploading..." with spinner is now provided to your viewing pleasure.

On Meta now, rolled out to the rest of the network as we speak.

Comment: Great :) You may want to add a space after the "Uploading", but that's minor.

Comment: Bug: On MSO, there still isn't any progress bar for the copy-paste upload functionality.

Comment: @Manishearth - Right. Space added and paste/drag-n-drop will now show the message too. Just wait for the next build.

Comment: Thanks! :) :) :) :) (extra smileys for 15 char limit)